# When does reflection stop being worth it?

Tags: python, reflection, coding-style

I just refactored a script with about twelve, nearly identical, one-liners to one that uses reflection to dynamically bind static methods to a class.

The refactored version [**can be found here**](https://github.com/yarian/brewerydb/blob/68144495111d6302cf781e29267909558a8a05f2/brewerydb.py).
And [**before refactoring here**](https://github.com/yarian/brewerydb/blob/d2d3c0dea8c81de147ea59e60760d699408123cd/brewerydb.py).

My question is: Does this seem over-engineered? Am I chasing some academic elegance that is in practice, worse than the obvious way? The refactored form is way shorter (about 70 lines) and more "beautiful" (for some defined notion of beauty), but a novice programmer might not understand it at all.

Comment: You might want to fix those links and make them permanently available (using full hashes instead of branch names) for future reference.

Comment: @poke Done. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with the "naive" approach is maintainability - you have 12 times more methods to maintain, debug and test. Imagine you need to add an extra parameter to all of them... with time, the methods will become very similar but not exactly the same. So the "complicated" approach may pay off with time.

By the way, there's a bug in one of the 28 "naive" methods which is not present in the rest 27 of them :)

Comment: Hahaha I noticed the bug when I refactored. That's almost a suggestion to use the non-naive one I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

Code should be easy to read and easy (unbuggy) to write. Short one is easy to write, harder to understand.

If you had to choose one, I'd go for the shorter one just because it's less likely to hit a bug. Comment heavily on how it works, maybe with examples of what it's supposed to return. If possible, minimize repetition.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would avoid answering these questions since I'm at the lower end of the novice level you mention, but since you mentioned it... :)

I find the more 'engineered' version easier to digest, specifically because it has fewer of the one-liners you mention. The conceptual leap to understand what is going on in the second version only takes a bit for someone like me (again, super novice) to follow, but once that part soaks in, the relative simplicity/elegance of the design (and more visible grouping of methods-to-be-declared) far outweighs any added time to understand the concept.

Again, my opinion is the last one that really matters, but if I find myself reading someone else's code (or my own) and after a minute thinking "Ah, now that is a good way to do things" (as opposed to "Alright, now what was I thinking when I wrote this and how does it work again?"), I feel like it is at the right spot (which is where I ended with yours).

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be, to keep the code as simple and as direct as possible. Which means it should be understandable by novice and experts alike.

If your code is kept *to-the-point*, it will be easy to modify and extend, even by novices or intermediate programmers. The ability to modify evolves the 'solution'. An evolved solution is an example of a good solution :-).

By the way I believe that this question belongs on [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I could be wrong.

Comment: I had a hard time choosing a home for this. I don't think it quite fits Code Review because I am not really looking for feedback on the code as a whole, but rather on its use of reflection in specific. Could be wrong as well though. Thanks for telling me about Code Review though, didn't know that existed!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Simplicty and elegance must be balanced with productivity and practice.]